# protobuf-net Serialization returns empty array

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I use "protobuf-net" for Serializing a structure, but it returns an empty array.

```
public static byte[] PacketToArray(Packet packet)
{
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

    Serializer.Serialize(stream, packet);
    byte[] packetArray = stream.GetBuffer();

    stream.Close();

    return packetArray;
}
```

packetArray[] ist at the ending "{byte[0]}" but there should be some data in.
The data of "packet" is:

```
[ProtoContract]
public struct Packet
{
    [ProtoMember(1)] 
    public int opcode;

    [ProtoMember(2)] 
    public string message;
}
```

And in the testings the values vor opcode is 0 and for message its null.
Where is the Problem?

Comment: I suggest you call `ToByteArray()` instead of `GetBuffer()` - it won't fix this problem, but it *will* give you a byte array with the right amount of data, when you've got the rest working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And in the testings the values vor opcode is 0 and for message its null. Where is the Problem?

What makes you think there is a problem? 0 bytes is perfectly legal for protobuf-net, and is expected in this case as there is nothing interesting to serialize; it can deserialize a `0` and a `null` without needing any external data. The key point here: if you *deserialize* that same zero bytes, you ***will get back*** a `Packet` with a `0` opcode and a `null` message. Job done.

If you want it to handle "framing" so that multiple messages can be read separately, then use `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` (and `DeserializeWithLengthPrefix`), but: no problem here.

Actually, there is a bug in your code, though:

```
byte[] packetArray = stream.GetBuffer();
```

If you use `GetBuffer()` without also tracking the `.Length`, you will get the *oversized* backing buffer, which contains garbage (in this case zeros). Use `ToArray()` instead. So:

```
public static byte[] PacketToArray(Packet packet) {
    using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) {
        Serializer.Serialize(stream, packet); // or SerializeWithLengthPrefix
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```